# How to set the minima and maxima in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

test = pd.DataFrame()
test['price'] = perf.price
test = test.dropna()
# reindex so index is int count
test.reset_index(inplace=True)

# get the peaks and valleys for the data set
peaks = argrelextrema(test.price.values, np.greater)
valleys = argrelextrema(test.price.values, np.less)
```

perf.price is a dataframe column.
I want to basically add two new columns to the test dataframe: last_peak and last_valley with the price of the last peak or valley but I cant get it to work.

argrelextrema returns a numpy array so I have converted to a pd.Series but

```
test.index.isin( peakSeries )
```

is giving odd results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**Example data:** `perf = pd.DataFrame({'price':[100.1, 1.1, 3.5, 400, 3.1, 651, 39]})`

**Added code:**

```
test['peaks'] = False
test['valleys'] = False
test['peaks'].loc[peaks] = True
test['valleys'].loc[valleys] = True
```

**Example output:**

```
   index  price  peaks  valleys
0      0  100.1  False    False
1      1    1.1  False     True
2      2    3.5  False    False
3      3  400.0   True    False
4      4    3.1  False     True
5      5  651.0   True    False
6      6   39.0  False    False
```

If you want to add a column with last peak and valley:

```
test['last_peak'] = test.loc[peaks[0][-1]].price
test['last_valley'] = test.loc[valleys[0][-1]].price
```

**Output:**

```
   index  price  peaks  valleys  last_peak  last_valley
0      0  100.1  False    False      651.0          3.1
1      1    1.1  False     True      651.0          3.1
2      2    3.5  False    False      651.0          3.1
3      3  400.0   True    False      651.0          3.1
4      4    3.1  False     True      651.0          3.1
5      5  651.0   True    False      651.0          3.1
6      6   39.0  False    False      651.0          3.1
```

Is it what you want?

Comment: @user2330270 or you mean last peak like `last peak before this raw` and not at all?